# How do I return a value from a second function in PHP?

Tags: php, function, return

I'm a green green newbie trying to write a simple program in PHP. I use an HTML form to ask a "diner" to select an entree, which sends the choice to a PHP program.The PHP program is supposed to echo the entree choice, suggest a drink to the diner, and then tell the diner what the cost of the entree, drink is--including tax and tip.

The first function select_beverage accepts the choice of entree and echoes out the suggested drink and drink price. It then calls function wallet_buster which calculates the taxed cost of the bill. `Wallet_buster()` is then supposed to return the taxed cost back to `select_beverage()` which in turn should return the taxed cost back to the variable that called select_beverage.

I can get a simplified version of this program to work but not this beast. My teacher suggested that I save the value returned from wallet_buster as a variable, which I would then return at  the end of the `if/else` cascade. I've tried to follow that suggestion in this code but it's not working. I've also tried

```
return wallet_buster($steak_price, $steak_drink_price);
```

in each `if/else` function but that's not working either.

Thanks in advance for any enlightenment you can provide!

```
<?php

echo "<h3>Thank you for dining at Elysium Excelsior</h3><br>";

function wallet_buster($entree_price, $drink_price) {
    $taxed_cost = 1.1 * ($entree_price + $drink_price);
    echo "<br/>";

    return $taxed_cost;   
}

function select_beverage($dinner) {
    $steak_price = 27.50;
    $steak_drink = "Justin Cabernet Sauvignon"; 
    $steak_drink_price = 13.15; 

    $salmon_price = 24.95;
    $salmon_drink = "Russian River Pinot Noir"; 
    $salmon_drink_price = 12.25; 

    $barbecue_pork_price = 22.99;
    $barbecue_pork_drink = "Dogfish Head 120 Minute IPA";
    $barbecue_pork_drink_price = 7.99;

    $chicken_price = 21.50;
    $chicken_drink = "Blue Nun Sauvignon Blanc";
    $chicken_drink_price = 12.25; 

    if ($dinner == "1") { 
        echo "The filet mignon pairs wonderfully with a glass of " . $steak_drink .
        at a price of $" . $steak_drink_price . ".<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        $receipt = wallet_buster($steak_price, $steak_drink_price);
}
else if ($dinner == "2") {    
    echo "A glass of " . $salmon_drink . " for a luxuriously priced $" .
                 $salmon_drink_price . " is a wonderful complement to our
    salmon."".<br/>"; 
    echo "<br/>";
    $receipt = wallet_buster($steak_price, $steak_drink_price);    
}
else if ($dinner == "3") { 
    echo "Try a pint of " . $barbecue_pork_drink . " for only $" .
    $barbecue_pork_drink_price . "."".<br/>"; 
    echo "<br/>";
    $receipt = wallet_buster($steak_price, $steak_drink_price);
}
else if ($dinner == "4") { 
    echo "Stiller and Meara invite you to try " . $chicken_drink . " at $" . 
    $chicken_drink_price . " per glass with the chicken!"".<br/>"; 
    echo "<br/>";
    $receipt = wallet_buster($steak_price, $steak_drink_price);
}
else {
    echo "Please select an entree from our drop-down menu and we will recommend
    a beverage suited to your choice.";
    echo "<br/>";
}

return $receipt;

}

$dinner = $_GET["entree"];

$big_deal_meal = select_beverage($dinner);

echo "<br>";
echo "We encourage our patrons to tip well; given your menu selections, we              `  `believe your bill should be : $" . (1.25 * $big_deal_meal);

?>
```

Comment: What is this program doing that is not expected or desired behavior?  Just having a hard time going through all of the code to find problems -- if you could help us hone in in the exact problem you're having (a certain variable isn't printing correctly, etc.) then it would be an immense help.

Comment: you can see the syntax errors based on the colour codeing.

Comment: You probably want to pass in different variables in each of the four cases: 1: `$steak_price, $steak_drink_price`,  2: `$salmon_drink, $salmon_drink_price`,  3: `$barbecue_pork_drink, barbecue_pork_drink_price`, 4:  `$chicken_drink, $chicken_drink_price`.. It simply does not make much sense passing in the same unchanged variables in each case (since right now all 4 cases does the same thing). But perhaps your problem was something else...?

Comment: I'd also like to point out that the current code is completely broken when it comes to qoutes (starting/ending strings). Perhaps an error when pasting the code here? example. `. " per glass with the chicken!"".<br/>";` should be `. " per glass with the chicken!<br/>";`  and  `$steak_drink . at a price of $"` should be `$steak_drink . "at a price of $"`

Comment: as a wine snob i would like to point out that Pinot Noir with salmon is a terrible choose.

Comment: Any luck making this work?

Comment: Yes, pyriccrash, it now works. Sorry for not responding sooner! Thanks very much to you and everyone else. Am grateful for all the suggestions on the code and debugging tips. BTW points to ippi for catching that I was passing in steak dinner's arguments for EVERY kind of dinner choice. Not even my OST teacher was catching that...LOL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is mostly working, you simply misplaced some quotes and concatenation. Adding quotes where they shouldn't be or forgetting to add them where needed will cause PHP to misinterpret your code. You might consider using a code editor or IDE to avoid this in the future. They will highlight your code to alert you when you make a mistake like missing a quote. An IDE like Netbeans will constantly check your code for syntactical mistakes.

Enabling error reporting in your PHP configuration will also give you useful hints about what is going wrong in your scripts.

Here is the working code:

```
<?php

echo "<h3>Thank you for dining at Elysium Excelsior</h3><br>";

function wallet_buster($entree_price, $drink_price) {

$taxed_cost = 1.1 * ($entree_price + $drink_price);
echo "<br/>";

return $taxed_cost;

}



function select_beverage($dinner) {

$steak_price = 27.50;
$steak_drink = "Justin Cabernet Sauvignon"; 
$steak_drink_price = 13.15; 

$salmon_price = 24.95;
$salmon_drink = "Russian River Pinot Noir"; 
$salmon_drink_price = 12.25; 

$barbecue_pork_price = 22.99;
$barbecue_pork_drink = "Dogfish Head 120 Minute IPA";
$barbecue_pork_drink_price = 7.99;

$chicken_price = 21.50;
$chicken_drink = "Blue Nun Sauvignon Blanc";
$chicken_drink_price = 12.25; 

if ($dinner == "1") { 
echo "The filet mignon pairs wonderfully with a glass of " . $steak_drink . "
at a price of $" . $steak_drink_price . ".<br/>";
echo "<br/>";
$receipt = wallet_buster($steak_price, $steak_drink_price);

}

else if ($dinner == "2") {    
echo "A glass of " . $salmon_drink . " for a luxuriously priced $" .
                 $salmon_drink_price . " is a wonderful complement to our salmon <br/>"; 
echo "<br/>";
$receipt = wallet_buster($steak_price, $steak_drink_price);    
}

else if ($dinner == "3") { 
echo "Try a pint of " . $barbecue_pork_drink . " for only $" .
$barbecue_pork_drink_price . ". <br/>"; 
echo "<br/>";
$receipt = wallet_buster($steak_price, $steak_drink_price);
}

else if ($dinner == "4") { 
echo "Stiller and Meara invite you to try " . $chicken_drink . " at $" . 
$chicken_drink_price . " per glass with the chicken! <br/>"; 
echo "<br/>";
$receipt = wallet_buster($steak_price, $steak_drink_price);
}

else {
echo "Please select an entree from our drop-down menu and we will recommend
a beverage suited to your choice.";
echo "<br/>";
}

return $receipt;

}

$dinner = $_GET["entree"];



$big_deal_meal = select_beverage($dinner);



echo "<br>";
echo "We encourage our patrons to tip well; given your menu selections, we believe your bill should be : $" . (1.25 * $big_deal_meal);
?>
```

Also note that you do not need to concatenate (with a '.') the text and html. Only when you're mixing in PHP code like variables.

So this: `"<span>" . "I am a string" . "</span><br>";` is unnecessary. This: `"<span>I am a string</span><br>";` is just fine and easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about IDEs! BTW we all missed that I was passing in steak dinner's arguments for EVERY kind of dinner. I caught that once I got the final suggested cost of the meal to show up.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
function select_beverage($dinner) {
    $steak_price = 27.50;
    $steak_drink = "Justin Cabernet Sauvignon"; 
    $steak_drink_price = 13.15; 

    $salmon_price = 24.95;
    $salmon_drink = "Russian River Pinot Noir"; 
    $salmon_drink_price = 12.25; 

    $barbecue_pork_price = 22.99;
    $barbecue_pork_drink = "Dogfish Head 120 Minute IPA";
    $barbecue_pork_drink_price = 7.99;

    $chicken_price = 21.50;
    $chicken_drink = "Blue Nun Sauvignon Blanc";
    $chicken_drink_price = 12.25;

    $selected_meal_price = NULL;
    $selected_drink_price = NULL;

    if ($dinner == "1") { 
        echo "The filet mignon pairs wonderfully with a glass of " . $steak_drink . "at a price of $" . $steak_drink_price . ".<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        $selected_meal_price = $steak_price;
        $selected_drink_price = $steak_drink_price;
    }
    else if ($dinner == "2") {    
        echo "A glass of " . $salmon_drink . " for a luxuriously priced $" .  $salmon_drink_price . " is a wonderful complement to our salmon<br/>"; 
        echo "<br/>";
        $selected_meal_price = $salmon_price;
        $selected_drink_price = $salmon_drink_price;
    }
    else if ($dinner == "3") { 
        echo "Try a pint of " . $barbecue_pork_drink . " for only $" . $barbecue_pork_drink_price . ".<br/>"; 
        echo "<br/>";
        $selected_meal_price = $barbecue_pork_price;
        $selected_drink_price = $barbecue_pork_drink_price;
    }
    else if ($dinner == "4") { 
        echo "Stiller and Meara invite you to try " . $chicken_drink . " at $" . $chicken_drink_price . " per glass with the chicken!.<br/>"; 
        echo "<br/>";
        $selected_meal_price = $chicken_price;
        $selected_drink_price = $chicken_drink_price;
    }
    else {
        echo "Please select an entree from our drop-down menu and we will recommend a beverage suited to your choice.";
        echo "<br/>";
    }

    if(!is_null($selected_meal_price) && !is_null($selected_drink_price)) {
        $receipt = wallet_buster($selected_meal_price, $selected_drink_price);
    }

    return $receipt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you were pretty much there. You may also want to note that if you have a double quoted string (") as opposed to single quoted ('), php will interpret variables within.

```
$var = 3;
echo "The value of var is $var"; //The value of var is 3
```

Of course, you also need to remember to escape the $ for when you need the actual dollar sign (\$). You could also look into using [sprintf](http://php.net/SprintF) to make your output a bit more clean.

Another useful tip is going into the terminal and running `php -l <file>` to check for syntax errors.

```
<?php

echo "<h3>Thank you for dining at Elysium Excelsior</h3><br>";

function wallet_buster($entree_price, $drink_price) {
    $taxed_cost = 1.1 * ($entree_price + $drink_price);
    echo "<br/>";

    return $taxed_cost; 
}

function select_beverage($dinner) {
    $steak_price = 27.50;
    $steak_drink = "Justin Cabernet Sauvignon"; 
    $steak_drink_price = 13.15; 

    $salmon_price = 24.95;
    $salmon_drink = "Russian River Pinot Noir"; 
    $salmon_drink_price = 12.25; 

    $barbecue_pork_price = 22.99;
    $barbecue_pork_drink = "Dogfish Head 120 Minute IPA";
    $barbecue_pork_drink_price = 7.99;

    $chicken_price = 21.50;
    $chicken_drink = "Blue Nun Sauvignon Blanc";
    $chicken_drink_price = 12.25; 

    if ($dinner == "1") { 
        echo "The filet mignon pairs wonderfully with a glass of $steak_drink at a price of \$ $steak_drink_price .<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        $receipt = wallet_buster($steak_price, $steak_drink_price);
    }
    else if ($dinner == "2") { 
        echo "A glass of $salmon_drink for a luxuriously priced \$ $salmon_drink_price is a wonderful complement to our salmon.<br/>"; 
        echo "<br/>";
        $receipt = wallet_buster($steak_price, $steak_drink_price); 
    }
    else if ($dinner == "3") { 
        echo "Try a pint of $barbecue_pork_drink for only \$ $barbecue_pork_drink_price.<br/>"; 
        echo "<br/>";
        $receipt = wallet_buster($steak_price, $steak_drink_price);
    }
    else if ($dinner == "4") { 
        echo "Stiller and Meara invite you to try $chicken_drink at \$ $chicken_drink_price per glass with the chicken!<br/>"; 
        echo "<br/>";
        $receipt = wallet_buster($steak_price, $steak_drink_price);
    }
    else {
        echo "Please select an entree from our drop-down menu and we will recommend a beverage suited to your choice.";
        echo "<br/>";
    }

    return $receipt;

}

$dinner = $_GET["entree"];

$big_deal_meal = select_beverage($dinner);

echo "<br>";
echo "We encourage our patrons to tip well; given your menu selections, we` `believe your bill should be : $" . (1.25 * $big_deal_meal);

?>
```

Best of luck with the rest of your O'Reilly course.

Comment: Eagle-eyed pyriccrash! Yes I am slogging through OST's Intro to PHP course. My instructor is great but it can be frustrating to communicate when there's a time lag of a few days between code submission and response. Most of OST's instructors are great but I get the impression that they're swamped with work. Thank you for your comments and the pointer to sprintf.